# Win CE 6.0 ethernet read/write thread priorities

Tags: windows-ce, thread-priority

I am using win CE 6.0 and need to edit the priorities of the threads that are responsible from reading and writing from ethernet. However I could not find any piece of code responsible for this purpose. Do you have an idea where I can find them?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The priorities of the interrupt service threads can be modified through the registry. See [Real-Time Priority System Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910702.aspx) for information. Ethernet adapters fall under NDIS (Network Driver Interface Specification).